# Set the disabled property of the drop down list based on the state of the check boxon loading the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I want to enable a dropdown list box only when the check box is checked and disable it when the check box is unchecked.
I am able to achieve this through jquery.
The issue I am seeing if I had selected the check box and do a refresh it takes the default value i.e disabled=true for the check box.

Is there a way to set the disabled property of the dropdown list based on the state of the check box while loading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the state of the checkbox when your page loads, instead of hardcoding it to disabled.
So when the page loads depending upon the status of the checkbox the dropdown status can be updated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_checked = $('#checkBox').attr('checked');
  // handle the drop down 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayendra Patil. I have one more question. i.e the id of the check box and drop down box is got dynamically.Is there a way to get these values in this function

Comment: If the ids are generate dynamically, you can use class selector for selecting the element. e.g. $('.checkBox').attr('checked');

Comment: Hi Jayendra thanks a lot is there a jquery that i can kick off on loading the check box so that the ids can be get easily.

Comment: It would be tough to get the ids if dynamically generated. You can easily use the class selectors with JQuery instead of Ids. That would make it easy for you.

Comment: Hi Jayendra , Thanks a lot for responding .Could you please help with an example. One more thing is i already have a class selector to be called on changing the value of the drop down list.

Comment: If your class is checkbox_class for the checkbox element you can use var is_checked = $('.checkbox_class').attr('checked');

Comment: Ya this class will be triggered only when the selection in the drop down list changes.Is there a way to get this class triggered on loading the drop down box so that the disabled property can be set

Comment: If you add this code in the document ready function as i have mentioned in the answer, this will be applicable on loading of drop down box also.